# Good Design for Contact Apps - Custom Table Cell Layout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6

Note: After reading, please edit title if not appropriate.

I'm just amateur in iOS. I practicing the objective-C with self-task and I'm trying to create a Contact Apps without any backend.

Problem:

In my app, I would like to display name and image in a cell. How can I achieve this?. I've already tried by adding to the sub view, the label(For Name) and image view (For Image) to a cell. But, it gives more conditional check for each of the different contact types. Like...

```
//In cellForRowAtIndexPath,
UILabel *lblForCell=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
lblForCell.text=[arrForMyContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tblCellForContactTable.contentView addSubview:lblForCell];
if([lblForCell.text isEqual:@"Mom"]){
    UIImageView *imgForContact=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 60, 7)];
    imgForContact.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mom.png"];
    [tblCellForContactTable.contentView addSubview: imgForContact];    
 } 
//likewise condition increased for dad, bro etc...- bad design, Correct?
```

So tell me its there any other way to decrease condition.

Comment: You can use Switch condition instead of Multiple if conditions..

Comment: Is there any Pre-defined array like multidimensional array exist in Objective-C? I except like that, not only conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do. First create an array of Dictionary. Something like this

```
NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *mom = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MOM", @"Name",
                                                                @"mom.png", @"imageName",
                                                                nil];
NSDictionary *dad = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"DAD", @"Name",
                                                                @"dad.png", @"imageName",
                                                                    nil];
NSDictionary *son = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SON", @"Name",
                                                                    @"son.png", @"imageName",
                                                                        nil];

[contacts addObjectsFromArray:@[mom, dad, son]];
```

Second create a custom UIView class where you can render this dictionary with init method something like this

```
-(id)initWithContactInfo:(NSDictionary *)contactInfo;
```

Third at the tableView

```
//In cellForRowAtIndexPath,

NSDictionary *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

MYCustomView *contactCell = [[MYCustomView alloc] initWithContactInfo:contact];
[cell.contentView addSubView:contactCell];
```

Making a custom View gives you flexibility of customizing your view for particular cell.

I hope it helps . Best of luck